# how to check id TCB (Trusted computing base) is enabled in my linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Trusted computing base (TCB) is the set of all hardware, firmware, and/or software components that are critical to its security, in the sense that bugs or vulnerabilities occurring inside the TCB might jeopardize the security properties of the entire system.
For using SGX DCAP attestation I need to enable TCB on my VM , question is that

- how can I check if TCB is enabled?
- if so what is the version?
- If it is not enabled how can I install or enable it on my Virtual machine OS?